# Woocommerce How to get First Level product category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a url like this on my shop page:  `/product-category/footwear/nike-sb/`, but when I run this code here:

`$cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();`

it returns the object for `nike-sb`, I need the object for `footwear` returned at all times.  If I go here in my browser:  `/product-category/footwear/` it returns the object for `footwear` just fine.  But how to get the object for footwear at all times, if we are in the footwear, first-level, category?

So, for example, if we are at the url `/product-category/shirts/hanes/`, it should return the `shirts` object instead.

Using WooCommerce for this, but unable to get a grip on the category directly after `product-category` within the url.  Seems to only return the latest category components.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question I've had to solve and I published it [here](http://wordpress.iamdez.com/2014/06/27/woocommerce-get-top-level-category/)

One caveat: I did find a bug with this that I haven't had time to solve yet, and that bug is when you pass a product ID that is at a top level category already. For whatever reason it doesn't come back correctly.

This is a helper function and should be used by other functions that call their own actions/hooks to be run.

```
function get_product_top_level_category ( $product_id ) {

                $product_terms            =  get_the_terms ( $product_id['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
                $product_category         =  $product_terms[0]->parent;
                $product_category_term    =  get_term ( $product_category, 'product_cat' );
                $product_category_parent  =  $product_category_term->parent;
                $product_top_category     =  $product_category_term->term_id;

                while ( $product_category_parent  !=  0 ) {
                        $product_category_term    =  get_term ( $product_category_parent, 'product_cat' );
                        $product_category_parent  =  $product_category_term->parent;
                        $product_top_category     =  $product_category_term->term_id;
                }

                return $product_top_category;

        }
```